# Problema login codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

estoy empezando con codeigniter y tengo problemas con login del sistema no se si es la consulta a la base de datos en el model o el controlador, el tema es que hasta saque el encrypt del password y no me deja entrar siempre me devuelve el valor a la vista de vlogin y quiero entrar a la vista vrpincipal a través del controlador clogin. adjunto codigo 
// vista vlogin formulario

```
 <div class="login-box">
    <form class="login-form" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>clogin/ingresar" method="POST">
      <h3 class="login-head"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-user"></i>ACCESO</h3>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Usuario</label>
        <input class="form-control"  name="username"   type="text" autofocus title="Es obligatorio que ingreses usuario" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Contraseña</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password"  name="password" title="Es obligatorio que ingreses contraseña" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        </div>
      <div class="form-group btn-container">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-lg fa-fw"></i>Ingresar</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

// controlador clogin

```
<?php
```

/**
 *
 */
class Clogin extends CI_Controller {

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('mlogin');

}

public function index() {

    $this->load->view('layout/header');
    //$this->load->view('layout/menu');

    $this->load->view('persona/vlogin');

}

public function ingresar() {

    $this->load->library('encryption');
    $user = $this->input->post('username');
    $pass = $this->input->post('password');

    $resultado = $this->mlogin->ingresar($user, $pass);

    if ($resultado == 1) {
        redirect('cprincipal');
    } else {
        echo "no funciona";
        $this->load->view('layout/header');
        $this->load->view('persona/vlogin');

    }
}

public function logout() {

    if ($this->session->set_userdata('username')) {
        $this->session->sess_destroy('username');
        //redirect(base_url() . 'clogin');
        redirect('clogin');
    } else {
        redirect('clogin');
    }

}
```

}

?>

// modelo mlogin

```
<?php
```

/**
 *
 */
class Mlogin extends CI_Model {

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

}

public function ingresar($user, $pass) {
    $this->db->select('usuarios.Id_usuario, usuarios.user, usuarios.password, usuarios.rol');
    $this->db->from('usuarios');
    //$this->db->from('areas');
    $this->db->where('usuarios.Id_usuario', $user);

    $this->db->where('usuarios.password', $pass);
    //$this->db->where('usuarios.id_area = areas.id_area');

    $resultado = $this->db->get();

    if ($resultado->num_rows() == 1) {
        $r = $resultado->row();

        $s_usuario = array(
            's_Id_usuario' => $r->Id_usuario,
            's_user' => $r->user,
            's_rol' => $r->rol,
            //'s_area' => $r->area,
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($s_usuario);

        //$this->session->userdata('s_Id_usuario', $r->Id_usuario);
        //$this->session->userdata('s_user', $r->user);
        //$this->session->userdata('s_rol', $r->rol);
        //$this->session->userdata('s_area', $r->area);
        return 1;

    } else {
        return 0;
    }

    //return $resulatdo->result();

}
```

}

// revise la tabla y los campos están bien inclusive le puse clave sin encriptar no se que estoy haciendo mal . En el  modelo he comentado algunas líneas de codigo porque pense que era la consulta, puse todo en una variable de sesión '$s_usuario' que es un array. Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Si haces un `var_dump($resultado);` que te arroja?, en tu controlador.

Comment: me devuelve int(0), claro será porque el modelo si no encuentra resultado el else retorna 0

Comment: Ok el problema esta en la consulta a la base de datos, ¿Cuantos usuarios tienes registrados con el mismo usuario y contraseña?

Comment: No me logeo con el mismo usuario y no existen registrados con el mismo usuario y contraseña

Comment: Coloca esta condicional en tu modelo `if($resultado->num_rows() != 0)`

Comment: Me devuelve igual int(0) el var_dump($resultado)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100618/discussion-between-a-palacio-and-julio).